# saying could not connect when I press submit on my form to my database

Tags: php, sql, html

I have been trying to create a form that updates to my database but... when I click "update" just says could not connect !!! WHY???  I know it hasn't updated because when I go on to my database nothing has changed... :-(  .

```
<html>

   <head>
      <title></title>
   </head>

   <body>
      <?php

         if(isset($_POST['update'])) {


            $dbhost = 'localhost';
            $dbuser = '***';
            $dbpass = '******';

            $conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

            if(! $conn ) {
               die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
            }

            $Userid = $_POST['UserID'];
            $TableID = $_POST['tableID'];
            $Life_points = $_POST['Life_points'];
            $xp_points = $_POST['xp_points'];

            $sql = "UPDATE points"." SET TableID = $TableID". "WHERE UserID=  $UserID"."WHERE life_points= $Life_points"."WHERE  xp_points= $xp_points" ;

mysqli_select_db('womath');

            $retval = mysqli_query( $sql, $conn );

            if(! $retval ) {
               die('Could not update data: ' . mysqli_error());
            }
            echo "Updated data successfully\n";

            mysqli_close($conn);
         }
         else {


            ?>
               <form method = "post" action = "<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
                  <table width = "400" border =" 0" cellspacing = "1" 
                     cellpadding = "2">

                     <tr>
                        <td width = "100">UserID</td>
                        <td><input name = "UserID" type = "int" 
                           id = "UserID"></td>
                     </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td width = "100">TableID</td>
                     <td><input name = "TableID" type = "int" 
                        id = "TableID"></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td width = "100">life_points</td>
                     <td><input name = "life_points" type = "int" 
                        id = "life_points"></td>
                  </tr>

                     <tr>
                        <td width = "100">xp_points</td>
                        <td><input name = "xp_points" type = "int" 
                           id = "xp_points"></td>
                     </tr>

                     <tr>
                        <td width = "100"> </td>
                        <td> </td>
                     </tr>

                     <tr>
                        <td width = "100"> </td>
                        <td>
                           <input name = "update" type = "submit" 
                              id = "update" value = "Update">
                        </td>
                     </tr>

                  </table>
               </form>
               <?php
         }
      ?>

   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're mixing `mysql` and `mysqli` APIs, those are two different things.

Comment: It is now showing could not update...

Comment: Use `mysqli` or `pdo`. And use [**prepared statement**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) to prevent any kind of SQL injection attack.

Comment: $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
replace by this function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php
In that moment you can also remove: mysqli_select_db('womath');

Comment: ok so will it look like this after 
$conn = mysqli_connect(.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php);   ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few things you need to change in your code, such as:

- If you're taking only integer input for all of your `<input>` fields, then make the `type` as `number` instead of `int`.

  ```
  <input name = "UserID" type = "number" id = "UserID">
  <input name = "TableID" type = "number" id = "TableID">
  // and so on ...
  ```
- There are few syntax errors in your code. Also, your SQL query is wrong. So change your code in the following way,

  ```
  if(isset($_POST['update'])) {
      // your code
      $Userid = $_POST['UserID'];
      $TableID = $_POST['TableID'];
      $Life_points = $_POST['life_points'];
      $xp_points = $_POST['xp_points'];

      $sql = "UPDATE points SET TableID = " . $TableID . " WHERE UserID = ". $Userid . " AND life_points = " . $Life_points . " AND xp_points= " . $xp_points;
      // your code
  }else{
      // your code
  }
  ```
- `mysqli_query( $sql, $conn )` should be `mysqli_query( $conn, $sql )`. [`mysqli_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) takes the first argument as your connection handler and second argument as your query string.
- Since you're doing `UPDATE` operation, use [`mysqli_affected_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php) function to check how many rows are affected from this `UPDATE` operation.
- Last but not the least, don't mix `mysql` and `mysqli` APIs. Use either [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`pdo`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). Also, learn about [**prepared statement**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) since it prevents your database from any kind of SQL injection attack.

Comment: @AnwenEvans Right after `mysqli_query(...)` block. Please see the examples given the documentation, [http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php)

Comment: @RajeepPaul I have put in                                                          printf("Affected rows (UPDATE): %d\n", $mysqli->affected_rows);                        Where you told me to but... it is now showing=                                     Affected rows (UPDATE): 0 Could not update data:

Comment: @RajeepPaul here is the code=                                                                 $retval = mysqli_query(  $conn, $sql );
      printf("Affected rows (UPDATE): %d\n", $mysqli->affected_rows);

Answer (score 0):

It is saying "Could not update..."

Because your $sql looks like this after the arguments are passed:

"UPDATE points SET TableID = yourTableIdHereWHERE UserID=  yourUserIdHereWHERE life_points= yourLifePointsHereWHERE  xp_points= yourXpPointsHere"

As you can see, you ran your arguments together with the next parts of the query because you had no spaces separating them, ( oh, and you also used the WHERE keyword 3 times.)

Comment: What do I use insted of WHERE??

Comment: You would use WHERE before the first condition, then use AND to join additional conditions, like this: "WHERE firstCondition AND secondCondition AND thirdCondition" but equally as important is that you need to insert a space so that the words don't run together.